# Checking the specific type of a constrained, generic argument in Go

Tags: go, generics

I'm trying to write some code that takes in a generic argument constrained by `Float`. As part of this code, I need to call `strconv.FormatFloat`:

```
func Foo[T constraints.Float](value T, size int) {

    // do stuff

    str := strconv.FormatFloat(float64(value), 'f', -1, size)

    // do other stuff
}
```

It seems to me that I should be able to infer the `size` argument based on the specific type for `T`. I understand I can do this with reflection, but it seems to me that there another way to do this. I've tried the following:

```
func Foo[T constraints.Float](value T) {

    // do stuff

    size := 64
    if _, ok := value.(float32); ok {
        size = 32
    }

    str := strconv.FormatFloat(float64(value), 'f', -1, size)

    // do other stuff
}
```

but, obviously, this won't work because `value` is not an interface. Is there some way to do this or should I resort to reflection after all?